# Passing variables through paypal and receiving them back after

Tags: php, variables, paypal, http-post

When a user clicks on the buy button, I want some of their info to be passed through the paypal payment pages and back to the 'success' page at the end so that a confirmation email can be send. I've tried many of paypals variables as hidden fields but I'm getting empty variables when i try to retrieve them. Below I've tried paypal standard variables 'custom' and 'item_number'

The form side

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
<Input type="hidden" name="custom" value="2"/>

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="2DLZKMQ7G6DVY">
<input type="image" src="css/images/checkout.png" width="124" height="40" border="0" name="submit">
</form>
```

This is the retrieval after payment to test variables

```
echo $_POST["item_number"];
echo $_POST["custom"];
```

Both of these are empty. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'd like to know a few details.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been answered numerous times, but you can in fact use the **custom** field to pass Data to Paypal that returns in the IPN call.

Mostly you only need the one field since you can encode an entire JSON object into custom.

Your HTML all looks clear, so try

`var_dump($_POST);` and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I've seen the various responses and tried them however I still get an empty variable at the end, even with var_dump so I thought there might be something wrong with HTML/php

Comment: @SoroushShamsfard can you share the results of your `var_dump` please?